# Nav bar doesn't work completly with the logo combination

Tags: html, css

I just get this weird adjustment I'll drop my codes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IAyQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NUlR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5DqU.png)

how can I fix the alignment? thanks

Comment: Please don't post code as picture, but prefer copy paste

Answer (score 0):

Try put logo div to navbar and then change css

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-item: center;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work :(